# RVM project specific gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler

I've set up an RVM environment and installed Bundler and Rake.
In my Project I've got a Gemfile, when I run `bundle install` the gems get installed in the project folder that I've specified. But when I run `gem list` I don't see the gems installed by Bundler.
Why is that?
Thanks for your help

Edit:
And also I've definied the rails gem and it's version in the project Gemfile so I never ran gem install rails

Edit 2:
I've ran `gem install rails`. When I run `rails -v` outside my project I get 3.2.12, inside my project folder I get 3.2.11 which is the version defined in my Gemfile.
But why? Why did I have to install Rails globally?

Comment: what does your `.rvmrc` look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.rvmrc` write following code:

`rvm use <ruby_version>@<project_name> --create`

In my case `ruby_version` is `ruby-1.9.3-p194`

Once you navigate to your project path, run `bundle install` to install all the gems specific to your project.

Comment: It seems i don't have a rvmrc file, or am i missing something?
Anyway, it's working know, i just wonder why i had to install rails globaly

Comment: you can create `.rvmrc` on your app root.

Comment: that means if i create a .rvmrc file in my project folder where i define the rubyversion to use (which is also defined in my Gemfile) i won't need to install the rails gem globaly?

Comment: You need to install rails globally. Its just that you are defining specific ruby gemset for different projects.